# Images are not showing after installing the .apk of my app on notch android devices

Tags: react-native

I'm facing this particular problem on my react-native app. Images are not showing on signed apk but its showing on build apk for notch android devices. Everything is working fine on non-notch android devices.

I'm fetching images from REST api and showing them on ImageBackground tag.

I've already tried SafeAreaView tag in my code

Answer (score 0):

> **You should add your images in drawable folder (Android)**
>
> **Note : if you add images in js folder  debug build images will show for release signed apk it will not work**